# подключение базы данных

Tags: android, база-данных

Подключил БД но выдает ошибку ,подскажите ,в чем проблема.

```
public class ListProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Product> mProductList;

    public ListProductAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> mProductList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mProductList = mProductList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_listview, null);
        TextView tvName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
        TextView tvPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
        TextView tvDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_description);
        tvName.setText(mProductList.get(position).getName());
        tvPrice.setText(String.valueOf(mProductList.get(position).getPrice()) + " $");
        tvDescription.setText(mProductList.get(position).getDescription());
        return v;
    }
}
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "sqlite";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/com.gigamole.sample/databases/";
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    public static int roomLuks;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if(mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if(mDatabase!=null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    public List<Product> getListProduct() {
        Product product = null;
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getString(3));
            //productList.add(product);
            ///if(cursor.getInt(2)<=roomLuks)
           // {
                productList.add(product);
            //}
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return productList;
    }
}
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String description;

    public Product(int id, String name, int price, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lvProduct;
    private ListProductAdapter adapter;
    private List<Product> mProductList;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_product);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //Check exists database
        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
        if(false == database.exists()) {
            mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Copy db
            if(copyDatabase(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        //Get product list in db when db exists
        mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
        //Init adapter
        adapter = new ListProductAdapter(this, mProductList);
        //Set adapter for listview
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.w("MainActivity","DB copied");
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> 05-13 17:30:08.471 28481-28481/com.gigamole.sample.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.gigamole.sample.debug, PID: 28481
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gigamole.sample.debug/com.gigamole.sample.MainActivity}: > android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM product
>
> #
>
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>   (no such table: product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM product)
>
> #
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM product
>
> #
>
> Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>   Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>   (no such table: product (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM product)
>
> #
>
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1393)
>   at com.gigamole.sample.database.DatabaseHelper.getListProduct(DatabaseHelper.java:56)
>   at com.gigamole.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
>   ... 9 more

В `MainActivity`, где выдает ошибку

```
mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
```

В `DatabaseHelper`, где выдает ошибку

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product", null);
```

Запускается приложение все хорошо при нажатии изначально пишет Error copy database а потом при повторном нажатии  выдает ошибки которые показал выше помогите узнать в чем проблема?

```
05-14 15:05:27.371 5849-5849/com.gigamole.sample.debug E/MyActivity: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.gigamole.sample/databases/sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Исправьте форматирование в вопросе и приложите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Он вам прямо пишет "no such table: product". И это логично, так как метод `DatabaseHelper.onCreate()` пустой, ни что таблицу не создало.

Comment: а что я должен там написать?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, вы пытаетесь подбросить приложению заранее подготовленную БД. Было бы здорово увидеть полный текст ошибки происходящей при вызове метода `copyDatabase()`, но и без него уверен, проблема в том, что из-за отсутствия файла базы данных, `FileOutputStream` выбрасывает исключение. Обычно база данных и её схема создаётся в методе `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()`, но в вашем случае можно поступить проще: добавьте в начало метода `copyDatabase()` строку

```
context.openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Comment: да вы правильно поняли,и вывести ее в listview. программа все равно вылетает,полный текст ошибки я скинул выше,это разве не то?

Comment: Вы попробовали добавить код создания базы?

Comment: да ,добавил то что вы написали.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` из метода `copyDatabase()` что выводит?

Comment: а где просмотреть отчет по ошибкам e.printStackTrace(),не могу найти?

Comment: вот здесь выбивает ошибку в copydatabase OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

Comment: добавил ,что вы просили.